# Формирование multiple/form-data запроса руками

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, formdata, multiple, mime-type

По этой ссылке https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms представлен пример формирования multiple/form-data запроса с генерацией boundary=math.random; не может ли быть такого, что boundary совпадет с частью данных? Или я чего-то не понимаю. Код вкратце:
`boundary = String(Math.random()).slice(2)` и потом руками собирается запрос.

Comment: Теоретически может

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4.1 RFC требует что бы «the boundary delimiter MUST NOT appear inside any of the encapsulated part», так что по хорошему надо бы проверять

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ответ, вопрос закрыт. Получается FormData делает эту проверку, а в примере просто не учтен этот нюанс.